# I have a table which contain the CircuitID column and some other info

Tags: sql, function, loops, procedure

I have a table `Circuits` which contains a column `CircuitID` and some other info.

I also have a table `Ports` which contains `PortID` and some other info.

And I have yet another table `Connections` which contains `CircuitID`, `A_PortID`, `A_Facing`, `Z_PortID`, `Z_Facing` and some other info. The facing can only be 'F' or 'R' meaning front and rear respectively.

Any connection going into the "F" front is connected to the "R" rear.

Basically what I need is to retrieve a view containing the `CircuitID` and port id of each end of the circuit.

eg.

For Circuit "1" inside the connections table

```
CircuitID, A_PortID, A_Facing, Z_PortID, Z_Facing 
-------------------------------------------------
1             1          "F"        2        "R"
1             2          "F"        3        "F"
1             3          "R"        4        "R"
```

So the entire connections for the circuit becomes

```
1 "F" <---> 2 "R" <> 2 "F" <---> 3 "F" <> 3 "R" <---> 4 "R"
```

So for the circuit, the `PortID1=1` and `Facing1="F"` and `PortID2=4` and `Facing2="R"`

Since the number of connections for each circuit varies, I am thinking of using a stored procedure or function to get any 1 connection from each circuit.

With this, I can make use of the `PortID` and facing and then call another sub procedure or function to determine the next connected end. It will keep looping until there is no port connected to the remote end.

With this, I will be able to get the `PortID` and facing of this remote end.

Next I will perform the same function to check for the other end.

Finally I need to group the results by `CircuitID` and get each end of the connection PortID and facing.

Hope any one can advice on whether I should use stored procedure or function. and then keep looping and call another sub procedure or function. I'm not sure which is more suitable for this uses. Stored Procedure or function.

I've create a sub procedure just to find the next connection

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetNextEnd(@Portid int, @Facing varchar)
AS
 SELECT Connections.Z_PortID AS RemotePortID, Connections.Z_Facing AS RemoteFacing,
    Connections.Z_RackID As RemoteRackID, Connections.Z_Description As RemoteDescription FROM Connections WHERE Connections.A_PortID = @PortID AND Connections.A_Facing = @Facing
    UNION
    SELECT Connections1.A_PortID AS RemotePortID, Connections1.A_Facing AS RemoteFacing,
    Connections1.A_RackID As RemoteRackID, Connections1.A_Description As RemoteDescription FROM Connections AS Connections1 WHERE Connections1.Z_PortID = @PortID AND Connections1.Z_Facing = @Facing
```

Hope someone can also show any example of how to make use of looping in the main procedure or function to call the above sub procedure.

I've been trying for weeks and still unable to get it working in SQL. Please help me...

Comment: This question is painful to look at

Answer (score 0):

In the example that you give, the portids are ordered, so the smallest value is the first and the largest is the last.  If this is true, then then problem is easy:

```
select circuitId, min(portId), max(portid)
from Connections
group by circuitId
```

If this is not true, then you need to provide information on what database you are using.  You will need to use something like recursive CTEs to solve the problem (SQL Server, Postgres) or the `connect by` clause (Oracle).  Or give up (MySQL, Access) ;)  Okay, give up is too strong, but you'll have to do a lot of coding in the stored procedure.

Comment: The smallest value may not be the first and the last value may not be the last. Finally tried and able to use the main stored procedure and keep looping the sub procedure until no more connection is found. Still in progress of getting the required results. Not sure whether it will work or not.